# In Excel, creating new rows based on presence of data in columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am very new to most of this. I am trying to analyze account attribution a large Excel spreadsheet containing invoice information. My columns A:AF are all the data describing each invoice in our system (name of provider, name of person billed, date received, date billed, etc...). These invoices are assigned to several different GL numbers (up to 22 per invoice). I was given a long string which I was able to break down into columns 4 columns per GL attribution and which I appended to the end of every invoice, where applicable (AG:EL).
Each GL attribution has 4 columns (always in the same order):

- GL number
- Billed amount before taxes
- Amount of tax 1
- Amount of tax 2

I would like to see whether there is any way I can have rows created automatically to have one entry per GL attribution instead of one entry per invoice. I would like for the general invoice information (A:AF) to be copied onto the newly created rows. I would really appreciate your help on this as I feel rather lost!

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish from your description, but if you look into using VBA and make an "if...Then..." statement that will copy and paste the information you want depending on the value of the GL columns that should be a good place for you to start.